# Parallax effect with vertical scroll inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

Hi and thanks for reading.  I am working on a website and trying to get an effect in place that I'm struggling doing so.  I am trying to create a similar effect as found on https://nest.com/thermostat/meet-nest-thermostat/.  When you scroll down about mid way, there is a parallax effect that keeps the left object in place, scrolls text on the right and once you have scrolled through it all, you continue scrolling the page.

Any suggestions or thoughts on tutorials for  this similar item you may have come across or a Fiddle that I can reference?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/
and 
http://andyshora.com/parallax.html

The last one has a fixed position which I believe is what you're looking for.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was close with just some css and absolute positioning.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!